# how to add xls report as attachment when creating record in odoo

Tags: python-2.7, odoo-8

I've created xls report using report_xls module. Now i want to add as an attachment of xls report when new record is created. I'm using odoo v8.

```
attachment_obj = self.pool.get('ir.attachment') 
ir_actions_report = self.pool.get('ir.actions.report.xml')
matching_reports = ir_actions_report.search(cr, uid, [('report_name','=','timesheet.auto.invoice.xls')])
    if matching_reports:
        report = ir_actions_report.browse(cr, uid, matching_reports[0])
        report_service = report.report_name
        if report.report_type in ['qweb-html', 'qweb-pdf', 'xls']:
            result, format = self.pool['report'].get_pdf(cr, uid, [x.id], report_service, context=context), 'xls'
        else:
            result, format = openerp.report.render_report(cr, uid, report_service, {'model': account_obj}, context)

            result = base64.b64encode(report)
            file_name = re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]', '_', 'Timesheet Report')
            file_name += ".xls"
            attachment_id = attachment_obj.create(cr, uid,
                        {
                            'name': report.report_name,
                            'datas': base64.b64encode(report.report_name),
                            'report_name': 'timesheet.auto.invoice.xls',
                            'res_model': 'account.invoice',
                            'res_id': x.id,
                            'type': 'binary'
                        }, context)
```

Comment: It's not clear what your question is. The code in your questionalready creates an attachment associated with your `account.invoice` method.